# Formatar todos os objetos do tipo Date no CakePhp 3

Tags: cakephp, data

Em meu banco de dados contenho alguns campos com o tipo Date. Por tanto os dados são armazenados no formato '2016-01-23'.
Entretanto, quando resgato esses dados para exibi-los na VIEW, eles aparecem no formato '23/01/16' e preciso deixar no formato '23/01/2016'.
Sei que eu posso utilizar o método $array->data->format('d/m/Y') para obter este resultado. Entretanto isto seria muito custoso em termos de manutenção e produtividade.
Existe alguma forma de formatar todos os campos do tipo Date vindos do ORM em um único lugar?

Comment: Tu pode ou formatar no PHP e vai ser trabalhoso, ou ainda no SELECT vindo do banco tu podes usar um DATE_FORMAT(campo_data, '%m-%d-%Y') e já trazer formatada!

Comment: @ThiagoSantos - Infelizmente ainda não resolveria a questão do custo de manutenção. 
Eu também poderia criar uma função para converter a data no arquivo da 'Entity' relacionada a 'View'. Mas também estaria na mesma situação.
Tente imaginar um banco com dezenas de campos de datas distribuindo dados para dezenas de 'View'. Tanto o método 'Date_Format', '->format("d/m/Y")' ou o uso de funções seriam custosos ao projeto em termos de produtividade e manutenção.